# addClass and fadeIn does not work properly

Tags: jquery, dom, fadein

In my index.php I have TABLE with four rows. One of them contains INPUT class="sipPacket" the next TEXT the next INPUT class="sipPacket" the next TEXT. Every two rows are in the TBODY.

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><td><input class="sipPacket" type="radio" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Some text 1...</td></tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
<tr><td><input class="sipPacket" type="radio" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Some text 2...</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I just want that when I check one radio button the part behind the second 'tr' with text "Some text 2" in next 'tbody' was hidden and vice versa.
I did something like this:

```
$('.sipPacket')
.live('click',function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
       $(this).parent().parent().parent().addClass('on').fadeIn().siblings().removeClass('on').children('tr:odd').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

It hides the second element but does not show it again when I press the radio on this hidden element.

Comment: What radio buttons? Please add them to your HTML.

Comment: What about use `closest('tbody')` instead of `parent().parent().parent()` ?

Comment: sorry for that parent().parent()... I am beginer in jQuery DOM exploration...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will do what you're trying to do (but I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve, and there may well be an easier way!):

```
$(".sipPacket").click(function() {
    $(this).closest("tbody").children("tr:eq(1)").fadeIn().end()
        .siblings().children("tr:eq(1)").fadeOut();
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/5bfN9/5/). It gets the ancestor `tbody` using `closest` (which, as noted in the comments on the question, is much easier than using `parent().parent()` etc.), then fades in the second `tr` child of that `tbody`. It then uses `end` to get back to the original matched set of elements (which happens to be the `tbody`), gets the siblings of that element (there is only one) and finally fades out the second `tr` child of that sibling.

Comment: Great! This is exactly what I wanted! But after this I just added a third `<tbody>...</tbody>` and it does not work with it. With two elements everything is OK but with the third `<tbody>` not... How to show ONE of THREE, FOUR etc.

Comment: SOLVED...I just changed the second `children("tr:eq(1)")` to `children("tr:odd")` and it works fine for me!